# Elasticsearch - higher scoring if higher frequency search times

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have 3 Documents:
A, B, C
All terms are very similar, and internal score is pretty identical
And people searching B more frequently than A and C, but C more frequently than A.
Can I get score to order like B, C, A ?

Comment: How do you define "people searching more frequently"? :-) If you can quantify this in something that Elasticsearch can use, then it will probably be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the use case you described, you can not change the behaviour of scoring/relevancy computation. There is the possibility of [boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) when using e.g. match query to affect scoring when searching for values. But that wouldn't be appropriate since you only want to sort the documents.

So the information about the search frequency has to be a part of the documents themselves, meaning it has to be an own field. Then you can simply add a sort clause like the following

```
{
  "query": {
     // your awesome query...
  },
  "sort": [
     {
       "search_frequency": {
         "order": "desc"
       }
     },
     "_score"
  ]
}
```

The *challenge* in this solution would be to keep the value of the field *search_frequency* up to date. You can do that via the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html).